# Who was "Nitai" in Gaudiya literature?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

It looks like a pet name.  What was his real name and was he a teacher in that sect?

Comment: Please try to explain the source for Nitai.

Comment: I could google it and tell you something, but it is better if it comes from Gaudiyas. @vivika

Comment: The post without proper sources and a bit of explanation from OP becomes weak and less quality. Better it's, to try to explain it in the question. Otherwise, it'll I definitely invite close voting by most.

Comment: I am asking only out of curiosity - it is such a cute Bengali-sounding name. If thats is a capital offense (for the question), let the guillotine blade fall :-) @vivikta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full name of Nitai is Nityananda. He was Sri Chaitanya's best-known follower and friend. Nityananda was older than Sri Chaitanya. They were like brothers.

Nityananda was born in Birbhum district, West Bengal. In his early life, he was a Saivite. Later he got attracted to Vaishnavism. He met Madhavendra Puri and Advaita Acharya - the famous Vaishnava teachers. When he heard about the new Vaishnava movement in Nabadwip under Sri Chaitanya's leadership, he came to Nabadwip. He was impressed by Sri Chaitanya's teaching and formally accepted Vaishnavism. Later on, Sri Chaitanya instructed him to spread Vaishnavism in Bengal; he did that wholeheartedly.

Prabhu Nityananda was known as the most merciful. Prabhupada once said there is no limit to Prabhu Nityananda's mercy.

An incident took place in Nityananda's life. There were two miscreants, known as Jagai and Madhai. They used to terrorize local people. When Nityananda Prabhu heard about them, he decided to confront them and convert them to Vaishnavism. He decided to show them the peaceful way of life. When he approached these guys, he was hit by a broken piece of pottery. Immediately his forehead started to bleed. He then made the following famous statement:

> "You may hit me by broken pottery, but it won't stop my desire to give you my love."

Later, these two guys indeed became devoted Vaishnavas.

Reference:

1. Chaitanya Mahaprabhu: The story of Bengal's greatest Bhakti Saint by Chitrita Banerjee